# Invoke AWS Gateway Rest API from EC2 Instance

Tags: curl, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway, boto3, amazon-iam

I have Window Server 2019 EC2 Instance running and I am trying to execute Gateway API endpoint using nodejs in EC2 instance. I have install nodejs and aws-client-gateway-api package.

```
    var apigClient = apigClientFactory.newClient();
    var apigClient = apigClientFactory.newClient({
  accessKey: 'ACCESS_KEY',
  secretKey: 'SECRET_KEY',
});

var apigClient = apigClientFactory.newClient({
  apiKey: 'API_KEY'
});

var params = {
  // This is where any modeled request parameters should be added.
  // The key is the parameter name, as it is defined in the API in API Gateway.
  param0: '',
  param1: ''
};

var body = {
  // This is where you define the body of the request,
};

var additionalParams = {
  // If there are any unmodeled query parameters or headers that must be
  //   sent with the request, add them here.
  headers: {
    param0: '',
    param1: ''
  },
  queryParams: {
    param0: '',
    param1: ''
  }
};

apigClient.methodName(params, body, additionalParams)
    .then(function(result){
      // Add success callback code here.
    }).catch( function(result){
      // Add error callback code here.
    });
```

This method works fine however, we want to change API-Execution method

1. Instead of access_key & secret_key, use Ec2 IAM Role
2. Use cURL or Python SDK to execute the API from EC2 instance

Any suggestion on above both point.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code provided is sample code from documentation. How does it relate to Python?

Comment: Above code is sample code of nodejs package and it works fine. I would like to know how to use python sdk to execute API instead of nodejs.

Comment: boto3 does not have such functionality. You just call the api endpoint using curl or any python requests. Don't need instance role for that. But if you want similar functionality you can look at external python library [aws-requests-auth](https://github.com/davidmuller/aws-requests-auth).

Comment: @Marcin thanks for the quick reply. Could you share a sample code or example for curl command to call any API gateway endpoint?